# Click to call - How to hide phone numbers when making them

Tags: web-applications, native, voip, phone-call

Is there a way to make a call with click to call through a web or native app, while hiding both parties' phone numbers?

Twilio allows VOIP calls, can numbers be blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Asterisk you could connect both calls to a conference.